# How to plug custom distances with ELKI?

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, elki

I've already read the tutorial at ELKI documentation ( http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/wiki/Tutorial/DistanceFunctions ).

Unfortunately, I'm not grasping how to plug the generated .class with MiniGUI (or bash script for the provided .jar). How it can be done?

Ps: I know it sounds absolutely noob, but when I try to "type" the class name, as suggested, I get the error "The following parameters could not be processed: HammingDistance", for example.

Comment: Try giving the *full* class name. With package name. Make sure it is on your class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELKI will load classes via the standard [Java Classloader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader). Therefore, they must be on the class path or they cannot be loaded. An example call (assuming your classes are in the `bin` folder) is
 `java -cp elki.jar:bin/ de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.ELKILauncher`

Parameters are interpreted as follows:

- If there is a class with this name (including the package name!) it is used.
- Otherwise, ELKI tries prepending the package name of the expected interface. Which enables shortcut names.
- Otherwise, known classes (from the service files) are checked for *aliases*. For example, the Euclidean distance has an alias name of `l2`, Manhattan has an alias `l1`.
- The class **must** have a *parameterless* `public` constructor *or* a inner `public static class Parameterizer`.

Input assistance is built as follows:

- `.jar` files on the classpath are checked for service files in `META-INF/elki/<interface>`
- *folders* on the classpath put you in development mode, where a recursive list is performed and all `.class` files are inspected. This is much slower, but removes the need to edit the service files. Discovered classes show up *below* the ones listed in the service file.

Furthermore, the package `de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.internal` includes classes that will inspect everything on your classpath, and will report e.g. classes that do not have a parameterless `public` constructor, or a inner `public static class Parameterizer`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Erich, I was able to use the custom distance class I created! Moving further: Is there a way to access data directly using a BDID? I'm trying to get the medoid's data from the BDID provided from getMedoid() method.

Comment: There may be multiple relations (e.g. vector data, label). If you want the data, you need to first get the `Relation` you want to retrieve (i.e. specify whether to use a vector column or label column).